# Frame rate dropped caused by AdMob Ios

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob

I have been having a strange problem with lag in my game for a while and I have finally pinpointed the culprit. Admob. After doing some basic testing of my app with and without ad mob I realized that Admob was causing a 10+ fps drop once every 10 or so times that it was being loaded. Here is my AdMob code.

```
func initializeBanner() {
    // Create a banner ad and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-8237297232584070/6035957145"
    bannerView.rootViewController = viewController
    bannerView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,
                              y:(self.view?.frame.size.height)! - bannerView.frame.size.height,
                              width:bannerView.frame.size.width,
                              height:bannerView.frame.size.height)
}
func loadRequest() {
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    bannerView.load(request)
}
func createAd(){
    initializeBanner()
    loadRequest()
    openAdd()
}
func openAdd(){
    view!.addSubview(bannerView)
}
```

This is called once when the user starts the app. What is my problem? Is it common? Is there a fix?

Note: I am receiving the warning

> You are currently using version 7.19.1 of the SDK. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and bug fixes. The latest SDK can be downloaded from (Stack overflow doesn't allow link). A full list of release notes is available at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes.

- The link is a goo.gl say in the comments if you would like me to post it in some manner.

Comment: Are you showing the banner while the user is actively playing the game?

Comment: @RedBrogdon Yes, it shows up at the bottom of the screen? Is this not recommended?

Comment: It's not, and there's a couple reasons why. One is the framerate issue you've already identified. It takes CPU work to load and show an ad (some of them are animated, for example), and that takes away from the resources available for your game. Another reason is that people are much less likely to tap on an ad (even if they're interested in it) if they're actively playing a game, which hurts your clickthrough rate and revenue. You might consider an alternate format from AdMob, like Interstitials or Rewarded Video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common, on the other hand It is possible to check if the line:

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-8237297232584070~4978026344")
```

has succeeded and you can wait to load the game until then. That might help a bit.

note: No it is not recommended to show ads while the game scene is playing